# Fetch records with query Args in Go

Tags: mysql, go

I Need help for fetch records from table using Go.

My Problem is that i'm writing MySQL query and add another where clause i.e HPhone number, Here HPhone number inserted in data base with format like `999-999-9999`.And i passed this HPhone Number in format like `9999999999`. which is not matching with correct data base field value. And i used `SUBSTRING` for add hyphen between numbers but it does not get records but when i passed like `999-999-9999` without `SUBSTRING` it return records.

Here i demonstrate how i used this.

```
strQry = `SELECT * from table WHERE Depot = ?`

if HPhone != "" {
    strQry += ` AND HPhone = ?`
}

queryArgs := []interface{}{RouteAvailability.Depot}

if HPhone != "" {
    queryArgs = append(queryArgs, "SUBSTRING("+HPhone+",1,3)"+"-"+"SUBSTRING("+HPhone+",4,3)"+"-"+"SUBSTRING("+HPhone+",7,4)")
}
```

Help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should check whether the generated query contains what you expect or not, this helps you to find the bug. Probably, you don't want to perform the `SUBSTRING` stuff within your query - you could simply build it purely in go

Comment: Thanks for reply Nico, i think you suggest me that first i convert this Hphone into formatted HPhone number like 999-999-9999 in purely go then i passed to it in queryArgs interface. am i right ?

Comment: Yes - if that really is the problem ;) But the longer I look at the query, the more I think that this is the problem. I'll post an additional answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `SUBSTRING` you can use [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) like so:

```
queryArgs := []interface{}{RouteAvailability.Depot}

if HPhone != "" {
    strQry += ` AND REPLACE(HPhone, '-', '') = ?`
    queryArgs = append(queryArgs, HPhone)
}
```

---

If possible I would suggest you normalize your data, i.e. decide on a canonical format for a particular data type and everytime your program receives some input that contains that data type you format it into its canonical form, that way you can avoid having to deal with `SUBSTRING`, or `REPLACE`, or multiple inconsistent formats etc.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work as you are using prepared statements, and the argument you are building when `HPhone` is not empty will be used in escaped form - so when executing the query, it won't compare the `HPhone` values with the **computed result** of some substring, but with a string containing `SUBSTRING(9999...`